# Getting a GUI frontend for erlang programming?

Tags: user-interface, erlang

I've been looking into Erlang lately, and it looks great. I have one big problem though.

I would like to have a Graphic userinterface for my software, is there any 'easy to use' module, preferably cross-platform, that one can use for UI interaction with Erlang.

I've come across the "pxw" module in literature, but have not been able to find it anywhere.

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `wx` library is newest GUI library for Erlang today: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/wx/chapter.html

I wouldn't claim it's "easy to use" but it's complete and available by default.

Comment: I almost feel stupid for asking, but how does one install this? wxWidget's don't write anything about it and my Erlang installation just states that  ´wx:get_env().
** exception error: {wxe,unknown_port}
     in function  wx:get_env/0´-- could you give some pointer?

Comment: Did you do a `wx:new()` before? (If you're running on Windows, you might have to install [wxWindows](http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/) first. This shouldn't be necessary on most other platforms).

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in a cross platform UI, have you entertained the idea of writing a web app?  There is a new marvelous WebFramework for Erlang, named ChicagoBoss.  It's like RubyOnRails for Erlang.  But more powerful and scalable.  Check it out at http://www.ChicagoBoss.org if you like.

--Kai

Comment: I was looking at yaws for doing web-services, but it looked abit 'simplified' - this looks great :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use wxErlang, Erlang bindings to wxWidgets library. It's main site - [wxErlang](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wxerlang&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://wxerlang.sourceforge.net/&ei=F8fdTsTYPMbLtAat5_n9CA&usg=AFQjCNGyOYNLqY9gdv-Ncu12Yx3yjqG1EA).

And good tutorial for beginners - http://wxerlang.dougedmunds.com/index.php